# Magento 2: how to declare a custom email template for your module

Tags: magento2, template, configuration, email-templates, magento-2.0

In Magento 1, you could declare email templates directly in the `config.xml` like this:

```
<template>
    <email>
        <custom_email_template translate="label" module="modulename">
            <label>Custom Email Template</label> 
            <file>vendor/modulename/custom_email_template.html</file>
            <type>html</type>
        </custom_email_template>
    </email>
</template>
```

Then you only had to create the following file `app/locale/<lang_LANG>/template/email/vendor/modulename/custom_email_template.html`

How can we achieve that in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Magento 2, you have to declare your custom email templates under the `etc/email_templates.xml` in your `app/code/Vendor/Module` folder.

Based on the question, a working example would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="custom_email_template" label="Custom Email Template" file="custom_email_template.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Module" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Take note of the `area` attribute that can be either `frontend` or `adminhtml` and that was not declared in M1.

Then you need to create your custom email template under `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/<area>/email/custom_email_template.html`

Comment: Do we need to create new Module? For Contact Us in Magento 2 we have type `text` want to change `html`

Comment: @AnkitShah yes you need to create a new module to declare a new custom email template

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism. This above code at which place will work. Suppose i want this template at catalog_index_index (at product detail page). Then should we need to do?

Comment: is this enough to be able to use that template in email templates as {{template config_path="custom_email_template"}} ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism what we need to do if i need to use different email template for customer group ?

Comment: @ManthanDave that's a whole other question I suggest you create a new post for it

Comment: what is the best reason to decide what area to set: adminhtml vs. frontend?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, this is created the template, but if we load in admin and modify, not reflecting.I have changed some text in admin, then saved, but the updated text not reflecting

Comment: Does not work, I get **Error while filtering the template: Email template '' is not defined.** I tried to add it like this `{{template config_path="custom/email/usp_block_template"}}`