# Magento 2: How to change Contact Us Email Type?

Tags: magento2, configuration, email-templates, html, contact-us

**magento\vendor\magento\module-contact\etc\email_templates.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="contact_email_email_template" label="Contact Form" file="submitted_form.html" type="text" module="Magento_Contact" area="adminhtml"/>
</config>
```

I have followed [Magento 2: how to declare a custom email template for your module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114214/magento-2-how-to-declare-a-custom-email-template-for-your-module)

Can we override in `app\design` or need to create custom module in `app\code`? If we can override using design then it will be better, because don't want to create new module for this.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="contact_email_email_template" label="Contact Form" file="submitted_form.html" type="html" module="Magento_Contact" area="adminhtml"/>
</config>
```

Tried using **magento\app\code\Custom\Module\etc\email_templates.xml** But still not working. It's still taking Type as Text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new module for overwrite template config.

Your **module.xml** should be [Vendor/RewriteContact/etc/module.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_RewriteContact" setup_version="2.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Now Vendor/RewriteContact/etc/email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="contact_email_email_template" label="Contact Form" file="submitted_form.html" type="html" module="Magento_Contact" area="adminhtml"/>
</config>
```

After changing **module.xml** file you need to run **setup:upgrade** command.

Clear cache.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating new email template file in your custom module.

**submitted_form.html**

```
{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}
<br/>
{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}
<br/>
{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}
<br/>
<br/>
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}
<br/>
```

Now your **email_templates.xml** be like

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="jay_contact_email_email_template" label="Jay Contact Form" file="submitted_form.html" type="html" module="Jay_Contactform" area="adminhtml"/>
</config>
```

Most importantly, provide unique template identifier. ex: **jay_contact_email_email_template**

Now the html content would work fine.

Comment: Not showing on `Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Contacts : Email Options - Email Template`

Comment: Yes. Adding templates via code is not listing over there. I don't know why. But if you want your template to be listed there, you can create new email template from admin back-end.