# Magento 2: Header & Footer Not Displaying in Email

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, design

In continue with

[Magento 2: How to change Contact Us Email Type?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152988/magento-2-how-to-change-contact-us-email-type)

I have set my new template for Contact Us.

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{trans "Name: %name" name=$data.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{trans "Email: %email" email=$data.email}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{trans "Phone Number: %telephone" telephone=$data.telephone}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

When i "Preview Template" from Admin, then it's showing Header & Footer.

In the Email it's not showing. I already cleared cache & run all commands.

Comment: Make sure type of your template should be html in your email_template.xml

Comment: Yes its already html. In email i got as mentioned in question. Only header & footer missing

Comment: The content showed correctly?

Comment: Then you should probably check the email template selected in backend for the contact us.

Comment: Yes @KhoaTruongDinh Content show perfect in HTML mode. For other email templates i'm using same header & footer & it works.

Comment: @AnkitShah have you got solution?

Comment: Yes @AjayPatel added answer

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--@vars {
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/footer_template\"":"Email Footer Template",
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/header_template\"":"Email Header Template"
} @-->
```

This will solve issue

Comment: are you added in custom template in magento backend right?

Comment: Yes. This should be in ur template .html file

Comment: can you help me find the template path

Comment: i have added in submitted_form.html but not working

Comment: Please create new question & post  your code with that @AjayPatel

Comment: Ankit please check : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180205/i-have-created-contact-template-but-not-display-header-and-footer

Comment: any luck with this issue? I am getting the same.