# Magento 2: Override contact us email template using extension

Tags: magento2, overrides, contact-us

I followed below answer but could not override default contact us email template.

[Magento 2: How to change Contact Us Email Type?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152988/magento-2-how-to-change-contact-us-email-type)

I developed extension to override **form.phtml** to add new contact us fields. Now I want to add those custom fields in contact us email template. I tried as per above solution but it always use default contact us email template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override controller which sends email for contact us form. 
**Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post.php**

In this file line number around 57 you will get a code which sets template id.

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier(<YOUR_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID > )
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();
```

In this code replace it with your email template id. so your email template will be used to send emails.