# Header and footer are not showing in contact us email in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have override contact module and changed email type from **text** to **html** by following this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/152988/magento-2-how-to-change-contact-us-email-type).

I want to show same **header** and **footer** in **contact email** also. When I check the preview of the template in the admin panel, it is showing fine, but when email goes to particular email, header and footer in the email are not showing.

I have checked many other threads for header and footer not loading in the custom email in Magento 2, but none of those worked for me.

I have also tried to copy and paste HTML of header and footer into contact email template, but there was no luck.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not a proper solution; after too much debugging, I fixed the issue by the below process:

- Create a new template for Contact Us email from **Marketing > Email Templates**.
- Check the **preview** of the template and open page source of the template preview page.
- Copy **HTML source** of the portion in which email template content is being shown.
- Put the copied source into email template and replace the dynamic content with respective variables again.
- Save the template and apply it from **Stores > Configuration > General (Contacts) > Email Options**.

Now try it from the frontend. I hope it would help you also.